# Doing an upsert in mongo, can I specify a custom query for the "insert" case?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, upsert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mongodb upsert only update selected fields, but insert all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069897/mongodb-upsert-only-update-selected-fields-but-insert-all)

Say I have this:

```
db.Person.update({ name: "Ignacio" }, { $inc: { age: 1 } }, { upsert: true });
```

It will load the person "Ignacio" and increase his age.

What I need is... 
If the person is not found, when inserting add the field

```
{ phone: "12345" }
```

If the person already exists, nothing will be done regarding "phone".

I couldn't find how to achieve this in mongo documentation. Am I forced to first FIND the object and then insert or update manually?

Comment: You can look here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-340 it is in the latest dev but it won't be in stable until 2.4

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both comments were really helpful!!!